# Loading Telerik MVC tabstrip via Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, telerik-mvc

I have the MVC Telerik grid with one column as a hyper link. Whenever the user clicks on this link, I am loading a partial view using Ajax.

Within this partial view I have a Telerik MVC tabstrip control. The problem which I am currently facing is that I am not able to switch between the tabs of this tabstrip when it is rendered. Probably it is not able to reference its JavaScript files as it is loaded via Ajax.

I have already referred to the Telerik article of registering JavaScript files using the script registar:

```
<%= Html.Telerik().ScriptRegistrar()
    .DefaultGroup(group => group
        .Add("telerik.common.js")
        .Add("telerik.component.js")
%>
```

However, the difference in this example is that here the tabstrip control is not loaded using Ajax. Only the content is loaded using Ajax whereas in my case I am loading the tabstrip control using Ajax.

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it! If you face such an issue, refer to *[Telerik Extensions for ASP.NET MVC Manual](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-mvc/using-with-partial-views-loaded-via-ajax.html)*.